# calling a function within a function

Tags: php

I've had a look through several of the related questions and just can't seem to see the issue!

the following two functions are within my function include file and for some reason I cannot seem to get the check_orientation function to return scale to the display_months_news function.

I'm fairly sure I'm just missing something really obviously.

the display_news function

```
function display_months_news()
{
    //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $year = date("y");
    $year = "20" .$year;
    $month = date("m");
    if ($month) {
        switch ($month){
            case "01": $month = "January"; break;
            case "02": $month = "February"; break;
            case "03": $month = "March"; break;
            case "04": $month = "April"; break;
            case "05": $month = "May"; break;
            case "06": $month = "June"; break;
            case "07": $month = "July"; break;
            case "08": $month = "August"; break;
            case "09": $month = "September"; break;
            case "10": $month = "October"; break;
            case "11": $month = "November"; break;
            case "12": $month = "December"; break;
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>The date field is empty.</p>';
    }
    $nowdate = $month." ".$year;

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY sqldate DESC LIMIT 6") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        global $imgurl;
        $imgurl = $row['img1'];

        check_orientation4($imgurl);

        $comcount = comment_count($row['nid']);
        if ($comcount == NULL) {$comcount = 0;}

        echo '<div class="news-preview-container">';
        echo '<div class="news-preview-container-date">';
        echo "<P>" .$row['mmonth']. " ".$row['dday']. ", " .$row['yyear']. "</p><BR>";
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="news-preview-container-title">';
        echo "<p><a href='article.php?id=" .$row['nid']."'>" .$row['title']."</a></p><BR>";
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="news-preview-container-inner">';
        echo '<div class="news-preview-container-text">';
        echo '<p>'.ShortenText($row['body']).'</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="news-preview-container-image"><img src="'.$imgurl.'"'.$scale.'"></div><BR></div>';
        echo '<div class="news-preview-container-bottombar">Posted in '.$row[tag].' / '.$comcount.' Comments</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

and the check_orientation function

```
function check_orientation4($imgurls){

if ($imgurls == NULL){ echo "";  }
else {
        $imgurlshrunk = NULL;
        $maxsize = 120;
        $filename = NULL;
        $height = NULL;
        $width = NULL;
        $scale = NULL;
        $imgurlshrunk = $imgurls;
        $filename = basename($imgurlshrunk);
        $filename = "admin/uploads/" . $filename;
        list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize("$filename");
        $wRatio = $maxsize / $width;
        $hRatio= $maxsize / $height;

    global $scale;

    if ( ($width <= $maxsize) && ($height <= $maxsize))
      {

        $scale = "";
        return $scale;
      }
    elseif ( ($wRatio * $height) < $maxsize) 
    { 
        $scale = "width = '100%'";  
        return $scale;
    }
    elseif  ($height == NULL)
    {

        echo "empty height";
    }
    else
    {
    global $height;
        $scale = "height = '100%'"; 
        return $scale; 
    }       }}
```

Thanks in advance to whoever points out the silly mistake i'm missing!

Comment: Could it be that `$imgurls` is NULL on the third line of check_orientation4?

Comment: $imgurl definitely holds a value, and can't see anything stopping it from being passed into check_orientation so I'd doubt that is the issue

Comment: this would be the case if `$imgurls` is not declared as a global variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't store the result of `check_orientation4($imgurl);` anywhere. Try changing that line to this:

```
$scale = check_orientation4($imgurl);
```

Comment: Ah, for some reason I was under the impression the return pushed the variable to the other function... thanks for pointing out the error!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything with the return value of check_orientation4

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the return value of check_orientation4 to anything.

```
check_orientation4($imgurl);
```

should be

```
$scale = check_orientation4($imgurl);
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be returning scale into a variable of some kind?  Right now you're just running the function.  You should do something like:

```
$toScale = check_orientation4($imgurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're discarding the return value from check_orientation4, perhaps?

Comment: `check_orientation4` returns no value

Comment: It most certainly does, as all the other answers have pointed out.